# Как настроить SSTP клиент на Mikrotik RouterOS?

Tags: сеть, vpn, mikrotik

Есть задача подключиться к удаленной сети по *VPN SSTP*. Скорее всего, в роли VPN-сервера выступает *Windows server 2008*, точно не известно.

Для подключения, администратор удаленной сети, выдал

- адрес сервера *remote.network.com*
- сертификат в виде файла *RCA.crt*
- логин: *test*
- пароль: *passwd*

Настроил *VPN* на рабочей станции (*Windows 7*) - все заработало. Есть доступ к удаленной сети, хосты отвечают на пинги, по *RDP* можно подключится.

Попытался настроить на маршрутизаторе *Mikrotik* c *RouterOS v.6.34.3*:

```
/certificate import file-name=RCA.crt
/interface sstp-client add authentication=mschap1,mschap2 \
    certificate=RCA.crt_0 connect-to=remote.network.com \
    disabled=no name=sstp-vpn password=passwd \
    profile=default-encryption user=test verify-server-certificate=yes
/ip route add distance=1 dst-address=10.0.0.0/8 gateway=sstp-vpn
/ip firewall filter add chain=input comment="VPN" dst-port=1723 protocol=tcp
/ip firewall filter add chain=input protocol=gre
```

При проверке подключения (`ping 10.0.0.1`), в логе появляются такие сообщения:

```
sstp,info sstp-vpn: initializing...
sstp,debug sstp-vpn: IPCP demandUp
sstp,info sstp-vpn: waiting for packets...
sstp,info sstp-vpn: connecting...
sstp,info sstp-vpn: terminating... - no key for certificate found (6)
sstp,debug sstp-vpn: LCP lowerdown
sstp,debug sstp-vpn: LCP down event in initial state
sstp,info sstp-vpn: disconnected
```

Как я понял, подключение инициализируется, сервер отвечает, и на стадии проверки сертификата соединение обрывается.

Не могу понять, где я ошибся или что не настроил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> no key for certificate found

Требует файл с ключом. *.key. Сам сталкивался с этой проблемой, т.е. одного корневого сертификата мало микротику, не смотря на то, что настраивается только клиент. Как это обойти-настроить не нашел, просто вставил ключ, благо я и был администратором.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже ошибка в том, что был прописан корневой сертификат в качестве сертификата клиента, 
для проверки подлинности сервера достаточно импортировать корневой сертификат (что и было сделано тут: `/certificate import file-name=RCA.crt`) и включить проверку сертификата сервера на клиенте (`verify-server-certificate=yes`)

> RouterOS client would be to import the CA certificate and enabling verify-server-certificate option
>   https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Interface/SSTP

думаю, чтобы туннель поднялся, нужно было просто убрать параметр `certificate=RCA.crt_0` при настройке клиента:

```
/interface sstp-client add authentication=mschap1,mschap2 \
    connect-to=remote.network.com \
    disabled=no name=sstp-vpn password=passwd \
    profile=default-encryption user=test verify-server-certificate=yes
```